# How to set a views frame width? (Why can't I set it directly?)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, positioning

I want to reset a UIView's frame size so I wrote:

```
view.frame.size.width = x;
```

but it doesn't work, can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can't set width directly, do this

```
CGRect frm = view.frame;
frm.size.width = x;
view.frame = frm;
```

Comment: yeah, but i want to what's the difference between these two code style, what will cause if my code pass.

Comment: because frame property of view returns a new frame not that of owns view. and u set the newly get frame's width which will not affect

Answer (score 7):

When you call `view.frame` you get a copy of the frame rect property so setting it is with `frame.size.width` changes the width of the copy and not the view's frame size

Answer (score 3):

Here's one pass at *why*. Your code translates into

```
[view frame] // <- This hands you a CGRect struct, which is not an object.
             //    At this point, view is out of the game.
.size        // <- On the struct you were handed
.width       //             "
= x;         // <- the struct you were handed changed, but view was untouched
```

One other way of thinking of it is that there is an invisible variable there, that you can't access:

```
 CGRect _ = [view frame]; // hands you a struct
 _.size.width = x;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)changeWidth:(UIView*)view wid:(int)newWid{
    CGRect rc=view.frame;
    view.frame=CGRectMake(rc.origin.x, rc.origin.y, newWid, rc.size.height);
}

- (void) adjustViewtForNewOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation {
    //if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
    loadMoreView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, WIDTH, 50);
    headerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, [MLTool getPaddingHeight:self], WIDTH, HEI_SEGMENT);
    [self changeWidth:webview wid:WIDTH];
    [self changeWidth:tableView wid:WIDTH];
    [self changeWidth:  segmentedControl  wid:WIDTH-SEG_LEFT*2];
}
```